# Codeigniter CSRF error The action you have requested is not allowed though URL is excluded

Tags: codeigniter, csrf-protection

I have enabled CSRF protection for codeigniter application. There are many URLs added and excluded but 2 of them are getting "The action you have requested is not allowed" error while other URLs work fine

```
if (stripos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'api/controller1/index') == FALSE &&
    stripos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'api/controller2/index') == FALSE
    //URLs here
    ) {
    $config['csrf_protection']  = TRUE;
}else{ 
    $config['csrf_protection']  = FALSE; 
}

$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array(
                                    'api/controller1/index',
                                    'api/controller2/index',
                                    //URLs here
                                     );
```

So how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was using other method names so using index only works for index method in the controller and other methods need to be added so i removed the method name to disable the CSRF for the whole controller